# deleting pointer and use a field of the deleted object

Tags: c++, pointers

Here is the snippet of code that confuses me :

```
T* pop(){
 if(head == 0) 
      return 0;
 T* result = head->data;
 Link* oldHead = head;
 head = head->next;
 delete oldHead;
 return result; 
}
```

The `result` pointer is maked to point to the "data field" of head's object. After that, `head` is deleted. Does not `result` have to point to null or a blank space since the `data` field is deleted together with `head` ?

Comment: Does Link destructor clean up data? if not then no.

Comment: What's Link? What's head? I cannot compile you example...

Comment: data is pointed to by head, data is not deleted when head is deleted.

Comment: @RichardCritten that depends on if he wrote a destructor for Link, if in the destructor of link it calls delete on data then data is deleted.

Comment: @Eddge  only commenting on the code presented.  I agree OP should have posted a [mcve]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does not `result` have to point to null or a blank space since the `data` field is deleted together with `head`?

When you execute

```
delete oldHead;
```

the memory for `oldHead` is deallocated. However, unless you also `delete data` in the destructor of `Link`, `data` continues to be a valid pointer. Hence, it's ok to return `result` and continue to use the return value in the calling function.

If you have

```
Link::~Link() {}
```

there is no problem.

However, if you have

```
Link::~Link() { delete data; }
```

there is a problem.